# Shiny app that works fine in ubuntu is not displaying graphs sometimes in windows

Tags: r, windows, graph, shiny

I have a shiny app that has 4 graphs. Each time the user changes the month or the zooms in by double clicking the 4 graphs are re-written with the new data. The app works fine on Ubuntu but when I transferred it to windows I keep getting this error.

> Error in `grid::grid.newPage()` can find file `Users/michael/AppData/.....png` for writing?

This happens almost every time I reset the graphs in at least one graph sometimes multiple and sometimes none.

I'm using ggplot2 to graph these and here is what each one is like:

```
ecoQA <- ggplot() + theme(text = element_text(size=16, face = "bold"),axis.text.x = element_text(angle=-12, vjust=.5)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(x = file90$Test, y = file90$CorrectedReportedResult)) +
    geom_point(aes(x = file90N$Test, y = file90N$CorrectedReportedResult), colour = "green", size = 4) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = ranges$x, ylim = ranges$y)
```

Here I graph it:

```
ecoQA + labs(x="",y="")
```

Comment: Are you using the same versions of R and pacakges on Windows as on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes I am using the latest version of R 3.3.1 on both and the packages are all the latest from cran